# How to Convert DateTime String to UTC format in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, datetime, datetimeformatter

I have a problem where I am given a DateTime `String` which is assumed to be UTC -

```
2022-07-03T11:42:01
```

My task is to convert it to a UTC formatted string like this -

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
```

So it should appear like this -

```
2020-07-03T11:42:01.000Z
```

Here is my attempt so far -

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneOffset
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.format.FormatStyle
import java.util.Locale
import java.util.TimeZone

fun main() {
    val myDateTimeString = "2022-04-24T20:39:47"
    val ISO_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
    val utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    var isoFormatter =  SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT);
    isoFormatter.setTimeZone(utc);
    println(isoFormatter.format(myDateTimeString).toString())
}
```

I've played around with a few variations but I'm getting the following exception -

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
 at java.text.DateFormat.format (:-1) 
 at java.text.Format.format (:-1) 
 at FileKt.main (File.kt:22)
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks :)

Link to my example in the Kotlin Playground - [My Example](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: You imported the `java.time` APIs, but are not using them? Why not?

Comment: Never put quotes around the `Z` in a date-time formatting pattern.  Doing so treats it as mere text literal rather than treating it semantically.

Comment: Do you need to have the milliseconds always appear, even if zero? What about microseconds or nanoseconds, do you want them suppressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `java.time`, that means you can have the desired result with just a few lines of code.

The following steps should do:

- parse the input `String` to a `LocalDateTime`, which is specifically suitable for this step, because it stores only date and time of day, explicitly no offset or zone
- append the desired `ZoneOffset`, here simply `ZoneOffset.UTC`
- define a `DateTimeFormatter` for your desired output format (or use a built-in one, try them all)
- print (or return) the result, which is then of type `OffsetDateTime`

Example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val input = "2022-07-03T11:42:01"
    // parse it to a LocalDateTime (date & time without zone or offset)
    val offsetDateTime: OffsetDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input)
                                                      // and append the desired offset
                                                      .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    // define a formatter for your desired output
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX",
                                                Locale.ENGLISH)
    // and use it in order to print the desired result
    println("$input --> ${offsetDateTime.format(formatter)}")
}
```

Output of the example:

```
2022-07-03T11:42:01 --> 2022-07-03T11:42:01.000Z
```

Comment: In short: `LocalDateTime.parse( input ).atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toString()`

Comment: Thanks for the short version @BasilBourque, but wouldn't it truncate zero fractions of second? I thought OP wanted to print them in every case (at least the statement about how the output *should* look made me think so).

Comment: @ deHaar Dunno. Question seems unclear on that point. I posted a Comment there asking for clarification.